# How to send array in custom Firebase analytics event?

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

I use Firebase Analytics in my project. I created custom event that contains array of items.
In DebugView, I receive error code 21. This error code means that event does not support array parameters.
So, is there any way to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

For sending Array of custom models/objects you need to decompose your custom model into a Bundle object, later you have to create array of that bundle. Then you can add that array of bundle in another Bundle object & pass it in the event.

You can refer the below example:

Here I need to pass the array of Product in the firebase event:

```
data class Product(
     val productId: String = "",
     val name: String = "",
     val coupon: String = "",
     val currency: String = "",
     val discount: Double = 0.0,
     val brand: String = "",
     val category: String = "",
     val price: Double = 0.0,
     val quantity: Int = 0)
```

Like this -> `Array<Product>`

For this you can decompose your individual products into bundle like this:

```
val itemBundle = Bundle()
    itemBundle.putString("item_id", product.productId)
    itemBundle.putString("item_name", product.name)
    itemBundle.putString("item_category", product.category)
    itemBundle.putString("item_brand", product.brand)
    itemBundle.putString("coupon", "")
    itemBundle.putString("currency", product.currency)
    itemBundle.putInt("price", product.price.toInt())
    itemBundle.putInt("quantity", product.quantity)
```

Later you can add it in the final Event Bundle like this:

```
 val eventBundle = Bundle().apply {
        this.putParcelableArray("items", arrayOf(itemBundle))
    }
```

and after that log your event

```
 mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("your_event_name", eventBundle)
```

Hope this helps!